# defining output Solve

Tags: equation-solving, output

I'm just starting with Mathematica and I was having a small question:
How can you "define" the outcome of a "Solve" in Mathematica?
Here is an example from mathematica:

```
Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]
```

> {{x -> (-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)}, {x -> (-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a
>   c])/(2 a)}}

I would like to call

> x1:= (-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)
>
> x2:=(-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)

And then make a `list {x1, x2}`
How can you let this happen automatically, because with 2 values it's quite easy but I would like to solve a linear equation with many more solutions.

Comment: `x /. Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]`

Comment: {x1, x2} = x /. Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]

Answer (score 1):

You can have a list like so:

```
sol = Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]
```

$$\left\{\left\{x\to \frac{-\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}-b}{2 a}\right\},\left\{x\to \frac{\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}-b}{2 a}\right\}\right\}$$

see [ReplaceAll](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) for details

```
list = x /. sol
```

$$\left\{\frac{-\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}-b}{2 a},\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4 a c}-b}{2 a}\right\}$$

an use parts of your list, see [Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html):

```
list[[1]]
```

> (-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)

i.e. will be your `x1`

```
list[[2]]
```

> (-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)

i.e. will be your `x2`

Assuming:

```
a = Table[1, {i, 5}]; b = Table[i, {i, -4, 0}]; c = Table[i, {i, 1, 5}];
```

with `list[[1]]` and `list[[2]]` respectively you'll generate

$$\left\{\frac{1}{2} \left(4-2 \sqrt{3}\right),1,\frac{1}{2} \left(2-2 i \sqrt{2}\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(1-i \sqrt{15}\right),-i \sqrt{5}\right\}$$

$$\left\{\frac{1}{2} \left(4+2 \sqrt{3}\right),2,\frac{1}{2} \left(2+2 i \sqrt{2}\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(1+i \sqrt{15}\right),i \sqrt{5}\right\}$$